# Python twisted reactor undefined variable

Tags: python, twisted, tcpserver

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

but when I write the

```
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
```

eclipse tells me that it's an undefined variable..
I installed twisted and can get autocomplete for the import, but this won't work..
Google showed a few more having this issue but I couldn't find any solution to it..
Thanks!

EDIT:
The complete code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

factory = Factory()
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: This is not a complete program; please include the entire file, or we can't tell you what you're missing.

Comment: It's exactly what the tutorial says. but I'll edit and include the complete code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known issue related to the way Eclipse/PyDev performs static analysis.

If you look closely, the `reactor` object does not actually exist in the twisted.internet module at import-time.  The module is empty.

When Eclipse/PyDev tries to compile the bytecode, static analysis doesn't see the `reactor` object in the twisted.internet module and marks it as an undefined variable, even though it's actually present at runtime (registered through some Twisted magic I can't explain).

The workaround I use is simple, just add #@UndefinedVariable to suppress the error:

```
reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

Voila.  No more IDE errors.

Comment: You could also try adding 'twisted.internet.reactor' to the forced builtins (haven't tested, but it should work -- see: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try to run it outside of eclipse.  If it works, it's an eclipse issue.

Comment: how can I compile it outside eclipse? I'm on Windows.

Comment: It's python, you don't compile it.